# QMovie setting filename second time wont work

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am setting the Initial Movie File like this:

```
self.movie = QMovie("dotGreenBlack.gif", QByteArray(), self)
```

At runtime, i want to change it by setting:

```
self.movie.setFileName("dotGreyStatic.gif")
```

But this leads to frame-freeze of the primarly set file "dotGreenBlack.gif"

Anything else i have to do to change the Gif-Animation on runtime?

**Here is the fullcode:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import sys




class ImagePlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, filename, title, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Load the file into a QMovie
        self.movie = QMovie(filename, QByteArray(), self)

        size = self.movie.scaledSize()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, size.width(), size.height())
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        self.movie_screen = QLabel()
        # Make label fit the gif
        self.movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Create the layout
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.movie_screen)



        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Add the QMovie object to the label
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie.setSpeed(100)
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        self.movie.loopCount()

        self.movie.setFileName("dotGreyStatic.gif")
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    gif = "dotGreenBlack.gif"
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: black }")
    player = ImagePlayer(gif, "was")
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Gif Icons used in this Example:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to stop and restart the movie:

```
    self.movie.stop()
    self.movie.setFileName("dotGreyStatic.gif")
    self.movie.start()
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. is stop start newly allocating the movie player?

Comment: @user1767754. No, I think it's just re-using the existing one.